# Content changes history

Tags: 6

is it possible to view content changes history (author - date) ? We have many users modifying content in our website, and I'd like to know who made each change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Revisioning-module](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) is exactly what you are looking for. It keeps revisions of every change and offers you the possibility to moderate the content.
I use it for a few project and I'm very happy with the results!

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation and saw information about authoring-moderating workflow. I just need to select a node and view changes history. Documentation does not mention that, do you know if that can be achieved? For some bureaucratic reasons, it's difficult for me to install the module just to try it out.

Comment: You can configure the module so users aren't able to delete content (permissions can do this too). The Revisioning module will keep a log with revisions (archived) and you can revert the current version of a node to any previous one. So yes, it can be archived!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this case I don't want to prevent anybody from doing changes, just need to check who was the last user to modify a node and when it happened.

Comment: Yep that's right. And if you take the diff module BetaRide suggested, the circle is complete. You have a overview of what, who and when something has changed!

Comment: Did you successfully applied this module?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had the chance yet, but will do so soon and let you guys know the results.

Comment: Alright, great :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the differences between revisions the [diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff) would be handy as well.